# Android How to wait for an AsyncTask to finish

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` which acts as a client and get a string from a server and puts it in a `String`. After the task I use the response from the server but the data haven't changed yet - it's null.

```
connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        Client myClient = new Client(responseTV);
        myClient.execute();

        if (responseStr.charAt(0) == '1') {   <----- responseStr is null
            changeBrightness(Integer.parseInt(responseStr.substring(1)));
        }
    }
});
```

I assume the code keeps going after `.execute()` which is not very good in my situation.

Update: Added code for Client class.

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String response = "";
    TextView responseTV;

    public Client(TextView responseTV) {
        this.responseTV = responseTV;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(IP, PORT);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(BUFFER_SIZE);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            int bytesRead;
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        responseTV.setText(response);
        responseStr = response;
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code of `Client` class?

Comment: Right, use callbacks/(functional)interfaces :)

Comment: You don't wait for results where you call `AsyncTask`. You can get results and update your view in onPostExecute method of `AsyncTask`. You can post your `AsyncTask` class as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (responseStr.charAt(0) == '1') {   <----- responseStr is null
            changeBrightness(Integer.parseInt(responseStr.substring(1)));
        }
```

Use this code in `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask`. It runs on the `UI thread` and is exactly the method you need after finishing work in `doInBackground()`.